# Matching to one decimal place in Java using regex

Tags: java, regex

Hopefully a quick question. I'm trying to validate a double. Making sure it's positive to one decimal place.

Good Values: 0.1, 2.5, 100.1, 1, 54
Bad Values: -0.1, 1.123, 1.12, abc, 00012.1

So I've tried Regex here:

```
 public boolean isValidAge(String doubleNumber)
{
    DoubleValidator doubleValidator = new DoubleValidator();
    return doubleValidator.isValid(doubleNumber,"*[0-9]\\\\.[0-9]");
}
```

I've also tried: `"*[0-9].[0-9]"`, `"\\\\d+(\\\\.\\\\d{1})?"`, `"[0-9]+(\\\\.[0-9]?)?"`

Nothing seems to be working. I've been using  `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DoubleValidator`

Is there another way I can do this any reason why these regex's aren't working? I don't have to use regex.

Thanks

Comment: What about a number without a decimal place, like `1`, or `54`?

Comment: And what if the number has several leading zeros, like 00012.3?

Comment: Sorry I didn't cover that, it should also be okay to have 1 or 54. and no preceding 0's.

Comment: * cannot be used by itself, it basically says "the previous group/character zero or more times", .* would mean any character zero or more times.

Comment: Also: your "\\\\d+(\\\\.\\\\d{1})?" is almost correct, replace all \\\\ with \\ and it should work (apart from the leading zeroes), but you don't need {1} since \d by itself means one digit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will match a number and only a number with either a multi-digit pre-decimal point number with no leading zero(s), or just a zero, and optionally a decimal point with one decimal digit.  Includes match of the beginning/end of string, so it won't match a number in a larger string (*updated to not accept leading zeros, credit @Nicklas A*):

```
^([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d)?$
```

Use the `java.util.regex.Pattern` library instead.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Because you're putting the regex into a string, be sure to escape the backslashes

```
"^([1-9]\\d*|0)(\\.\\d)?$"
```

I recommend that you read up on regular expressions here, they are an important tool to have "under your belt" so to speak.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: If there can be no leading zeroes: `^([1-9]\\d*|0)(\\.\\d)?$`

Comment: @Nicklas: this will reject 0.3

Comment: @amit: no, it doesn't.  I tested it.

Comment: Requires a leading numeral to match decimal values. E.g., ".3" is rejected.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern.compile ("[0-9]+\\.[0-9])").matcher (doubleNumber).matches ()
```

would do the trick.
If you also want to allow no decimal point:

```
Pattern.compile ("[0-9]+(\\.[0-9])?").matcher (doubleNumber).matches ()
```

**EDIT :** following your comment about no leading zeros and an integer is OK:

```
Pattern.compile("([1-9][0-9]*|[0-9])(\\.[0-9])?").matcher(doubleNumber).matches()
```

Answer (score -1):

if you need to validate decimal with dots, commas, positives and negatives:

```
Object testObject = "-1.5";
boolean isDecimal = Pattern.matches("^[\\+\\-]{0,1}[0-9]+([\\.\\,]{1}[0-9]{1}){0,1}$", (CharSequence) testObject);
```

Good luck.

Comment: guys don't vote me down if won't tell me why I'm wrong.