# Regex to match only one even decimal digit

Tags: java, regex

I am building on the idea of [Jonah][1]: [Matching to one decimal place in Java using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168935/matching-to-one-decimal-place-in-java-using-regex)

```
^([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d)?$
```

This regex is the one I want. But my additional requirement is that the decimal digit must be an even number such as 0.2, 10.4, 100.6, 11.8.

I am thinking of splitting the string at '.' and checking if decimal digit % 2 = 0. How can I achieve this in regex?

Comment: This is trivial. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Change the right `\d` to `[2468]`

Comment: I know, I gave him some time to answer, then I thought he's struggling and had no idea where to start (i've been there myslef)... After all he did some search, found a close answer which was good enough I think (some people they simply dont know how to regex, we shouldnt expect much xD)

Comment: @Enissay We do still expect some minimal effort. This question does not reflect any effort to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `/d` for a decimal digit, you can just explicitly require an even number, like this:

```
^([1-9]\d*|0)(\.[24680])?$
```